# How should i pass a userId(or other parameter) to PSQL trigger AFTER DELETE?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jakarta-ee, psql

I want to pass a parameter into a trigger function, which invokes AFTER DELETE of entity record in my database. Is there any way to do it on application-level? Is there a solution using "SET" operation? Or maybe I can add a parameter to the same transaction, which is used on delete operation?

Comment: If you want to use `trigger` you have to manage it into the database engine ; if you want to handle it into the `application` level, you may run two SQL request into the same `transaction`, first request will be the job and the second one the job done by the trigger.

Comment: You have access to the ```OLD``` record (which holds the deleted lines) in such a trigger. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Islingre no, I want to get userId, who delete the record from the application level. I don't know how to pass it to the postgres, and I can't access this using `OLD`

Comment: Use a custom session variable [see](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97095/set-session-custom-variable-to-store-user-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of choices here.
 1.  You can set the application_name environment variable to the user name, and then retrieve it in the trigger.
 2.  You can expand the table by a column, and send the user name to the database in the insert/update/delete statements.

```sql
SET application_name = 'user name';

-- in the trigger:

SELECT application_name FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid = pg_backend_pid();
```

or

```sql
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN user_name text;

-- and in the trigger (depending on context):

my_user := NEW.user_name;
or
my_user := OLD.user_name;
```

Comment: Your trigger can refer to [system parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-info.html) current_user.

Comment: I made the assumption in my answer that the database connection user was not the same thing as the application user.   If I'm wrong about that, please say so.

Comment: How efficient is this in concurrency?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. I don't feel very confident about the first option. As for the  second option, it will require an entry UPDATE call,  before you can call the DELETE and have the trigger call my_user := OLD.user_name in order to get the user id you are hoping to get in this situation.  There is no way to pass / get from the trigger an SQL query parameter?  Such a functionality should solve this problem. Note that this is a problem with the DELETE operations only. For the insert / update you can get the user info easily, with a single SQL call.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution to this problem. My approach is the following:

I'm passing the username in the delete query as follows:

```
DELETE FROM products_images
WHERE id = #{id}
OR (SELECT false WHERE 'xusername' = '${xusername}')
```

Then at the trigger level, I'm extracting the username value using:

```
(SELECT SUBSTRING(current_query(), '''xusername'' = ''(.*)'''))
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION version_product_image()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
        INSERT INTO versioning.products_images (id,product_id,relative_location,is_main,creation_time,username,action)
        VALUES(OLD.id,OLD.product_id,OLD.relative_location,OLD.is_main,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,(SELECT SUBSTRING(current_query(), '''xusername'' = ''(.*)''')),TG_OP);
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO versioning.products_images (id,product_id,relative_location,is_main,creation_time,username,action)
        VALUES(NEW.id,NEW.product_id,NEW.relative_location,NEW.is_main,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,NEW.username,TG_OP);
    END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Note that in order for this to work, you have to pass the username as value, not as parameter.

Also note that I've only tested this with direct delete queries. Haven't tested it yet with cascades.

Comment: The current_query() and substring() functions inside a trigger really works and solves the problem. Thanks